How not to lose git commit file changes with Jenkins built in checkout
Im trying to map the diferent files that were last modified during the commit, with the command:
git diff --name-only --submodule=diff HEAD

But it results in only returning modified files during the piepeline process...
Inside the checkout phase of Jenkins I see the following checkout line:
git checkout -f <my commit hash> # timeout=10

By searching on the internet it seems that -f option will delete all history of changes and create a new hash commit.
I don't wan't this to happen, so I could grab the files that were changed.
Any ideas would be very welcome.

What's the difference between "files that were modified inside a Jenkins pipeline" and "modified files during the piepeline process"?

thanks.. I meant last last modified and committed.

Are you looking for this?
git diff --name-only HEAD^!


So far, this is just a comment. Please elaborate, or something. At least put a link to the doc for the syntax you're suggesting.
